# Insert query (mySQL-Netbeans) returning error message

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, insert

I have created the following table(to_do) in mySQL : :
td_id(int),td_day(int),td_month(int),td_year(int),to_do(varchar),td_done(boolean)

td_id field is set to be on auto-increment mode

While running the following code in  NetBeans, I get an error that says " Unknown column 'new year party' in 'field list'"

Could someone tell me how to get the code working?
Thanks in advance.

```
         Connection conn1;

         try{
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
                     String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myproject?" +
                               "user=root&password=abcd"; 
                     conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url); 
                     int datevar=31,monthar3=12,yearvar1=2012;
                   String data=”new year party”;

                     String strSQL = "INSERT INTO to_do(td_day,td_month,td_year,to_do,td_done) VALUES (“+datevar1+","+monthvar3+","+yearvar1+","+data+",0)";
                     Statement stmt1 = conn1.createStatement();
                     int StringrowsEffected = stmt1.executeUpdate(strSQL);

        conn1.close();
         }
         catch ( Exception e) { 
                       System.err.println("Got an exception! "); 
                       System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
                       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String constants (which yours will be since you're concatenating the query string together) need to be used with single quotes around them everywhere in SQL. Your query does not have single quotes around the point where you attempt to insert a value for the `to_do` column, thus it fails. The proper code is below, if you can see the newly added quotes:

```
String strSQL = "INSERT INTO to_do(td_day,td_month,td_year,to_do,td_done) VALUES 
                (“+datevar1+","+monthvar3+","+yearvar1+", '"+data+"' ,0)";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming its numeric fields only**, your first double quote (`VALUES (“+datevar1+`) doesn't look OK. Please correct as below:

```
    String strSQL = "INSERT INTO to_do(td_day,td_month,td_year,to_do,td_done) 
                   VALUES ("+datevar1+","+monthvar3+","+yearvar1+","+data+",0)";
```

**If any of the field are text type,** wrap the corressponding values in single quotes(`'`) as well.

e.g. if `to_do` is text type then,

```
    String strSQL = "INSERT INTO to_do(td_day,td_month,td_year,to_do,td_done) 
                   VALUES ("+datevar1+","+monthvar3+","+yearvar1+",'"+data+"',0)";
```